# How can I query for a domain's authoritative DNS servers to know if I have secondary DNS configured correctly?

Tags: dns

Situation:

- Domain registered with A (in this case godaddy)
- DNS hosted with B (in this case dnsimple)
- Secondary DNS hosted with C (in this case easydns)

I'm trying to figure out how to check, using the command line, if my configuration is correct. Here are the methods I'm trying:

- https://zone.vision/ "name servers" list
- `dig @xfr0.easydns.com example.com soa`
- `dig @8.8.8.8 +short NS example.com`
- `host -t ns example.com`
- `dig +short NS example.com`

The first two methods indicate that my secondary DNS is not set up correctly. The bottom three all list out both sets of DNS servers.

I could go on about various other commands I've tried with various domains which I think are or are not configured correctly, but I think I would just be confusing the issue. Maybe someone could explain to me, what is the information the first two methods are querying, and why are the last three "deceptively" indicating that the configuration is correct.

Sorry that I can't share the actual domains I'm looking at.

Comment: You can not use different providers for your nameservers... unless providers are synchronized between themselves somehow. The DNS is not failover-based: you seem to think that the "primary" nameservers are consulted, and if they don't work then the secondary are consulted. It does not work like that. All nameservers set up as authoritative for your domain (as known by the parent, aka the registry) will receive traffic.

Comment: "I could go on about various other commands" It is mostly useless when you obfuscate all the names. You can use online tools such as Zonemaster or DNSViz to help you troubleshooting your DNS problems. Alternatively, any of the registrar or DNS provider you use should be able to answer your questions.

Comment: "unless providers are synchronized between themselves somehow" - I have indeed set up C to pull from B (if I understand you correctly)

Comment: It is difficult to discuss without real names, so I will stop here... Try online DNSviz and Zonecheck tools. If both tell you your domain is fine, then it is fine and the rest above is irrelevant. If any of this 2 online checking tool detects a problem, then you have to fix it. Also did you ask A, B, or C? Specially you are saying the first 2 bullet points are what is troubling you, and those two points are directly depending on B and C. Besides, your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: which stack exchange site do you think it should be on? servefault? maybe someone with enough points to move it could do so...